# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Tags: python-3.x

I am executing the below code to connect to oracle database.

import sqlalchemy

conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://username:password@tnsnames:portnumber/host')

But when I testing it is throwing

```
import cx_Oracle
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

So I checked the cx_Oracle and it is there installed in the site-packages

Not sure what to do. So request to help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  How did you install cx_Oracle?

Comment: No there is only one version of phython installed. When I try to install cx_Oracle it, the pip install command is telling that it is already there in the site-packages.

Comment: Working fine.  Reinstalled python. It is related to Version thing as mentioned by Jones.

Answer (score -1):

make sure, you are typing the correct. It is `cx_Oracle`. Throws error if you type `cx_oracle`.